# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null at my logcat

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, picasso

When I am passing image url to Picasso then it shows me error "Target must not be null". When I fetch image from url using Picasso then it shows me error.

*my logcat*

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
    at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:682)
    at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:665)
    at com.example.instagramclone.fragment.ProfileFragment$userInfo$1.onDataChange(ProfileFragment.kt:191)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:169)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6595)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

*my xml*

```
            <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/pro_image_profile_frag"
            android:layout_width="161dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:src="@drawable/profile1">
        </com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView>
```

*my activity*

```
                Picasso.get().load(user!!.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile1).into(pro_image_profile_frag)
                view?.profile_fragment_username?.text = user!!.getFullname()
                view?.full_name_profile_frag?.text = user!!.getUsername()
                view?.bio_profile_frag?.text = user!!.getBio()
```

Comment: What is the value of `user!!.getImage()`?

Comment: `pro_image_profile_frag` is null. Did you forget to assign a value to that variable?

Comment: val user = p0.getValue<Users>(com.example.instagramclone.Model.User::class.java)
                    Picasso.get().load(user!!.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile1).into(pro_image_profile_frag)
                    view?.profile_fragment_username?.text = user!!.getFullname()
                    view?.full_name_profile_frag?.text = user!!.getUsername()
                    view?.bio_profile_frag?.text = user!!.getBio()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `into()` function the variable `pro_image_profile_frag` is null. Please check if it has been initialized before calling `into()` function. It should be something like this:

```
val pro_image_profile_frag = findViewById(R.id.view_id)
```